# Compilation error when trying to combine hamcrest matchers

Tags: java, generics, testing, hamcrest

I have a Queue of string and I want to combine 2 matchers in a single assert
The (simplified) code is something like this

```
    Queue<String> strings = new LinkedList<>();
    assertThat(strings, both(hasSize(1)).and(hasItem("Some string")));
```

but when I compile it I get the following message:

```
incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? super T>> conforms to org.hamcrest.Matcher<? super java.util.Collection<? extends java.lang.Object>>
```

- hasItem returns `Matcher<Iterable<? super T>>`
- hasSize returns `Matcher<Collection<? extends E>>`

how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the matchers must conform to ...

```
Matcher<? super LHS> matcher
```

... where LHS is a `Collection<?>` because `strings` is a `Collection<?>`.

In your code `hasSize(1)` is a `Matcher<Collection<?>>` but `hasItem("Some string")` is a `Matcher<Iterable<? super String>>` hence the compilation error.

This example uses a combinable matcher and it is compilable because both matchers address a collection ...

```
assertThat(strings, either(empty()).or(hasSize(1)));
```

But given the method signature of `both()` you cannot combine `hasSize()` and `hasItem()`.

The combinable matcher is just a short cut so perhaps you could replace it with two assertions:

```
assertThat(strings, hasSize(1));
assertThat(strings, hasItem("Some string"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Hamcrest contains instead. It will match when the collection has exactly 1 item that matches the value, but report an error if there are too many or too little items:

```
assertThat(strings, contains("Some string"))
```